# How to add ajax loading icon after click add to cart button on woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I would like to add a loading icon after a user clicks on add to cart for an item on woocommerce single page.

i am using below code in my site

```
jQuery('a.add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).append('<img src="/spinner.gif" width="20px" height="20px"/>')
});
```

But this code displaying the Load icon on Add to cart Button. I want to show the Spinner on the website like as checkout page spinner.

Also It works well after user clicks the 'Add to Cart' button, but I want to remove this icon after successful execution.

Please help me !!

Comment: this ll help to solve you issue   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504196/how-to-show-loading-icon-on-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce

Answer (score -2):

Try add code to .success stage and write code remove icon here

```
(Addcartbutton img).remove()
```